# How to set a variable containing a range-definition for selecting table columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, range

I want to set a range dynamically.  Say:

```
fromcol = 2;
tocol = 5; % or: = end;
nans = isnan(mytable{:,fromcol:tocol};
```

I want to dynamically construct a variating range to be used in the next line of code.  Can I set a single variable to hold the  "range" definition  (i.e. `2:5`) and then use it?

For example:

```
myrange = { 2:5 };  % this does NOT work...
nansok = isnan(mytable{:,2:5};
nansfail = isnan(mytable{:,myrange}); % err: table variable subscripts must be etc. etc.
```

Is there a way to do it with one variable holding the "range definition"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the braces, simply

```
myrange = 2:5;
```

This creates a vector `[2 3 4 5]` which can be used for indexing. See [this MathWorks article](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) on indexing for more information.

---

If you want to group the indices, you can use parentheses

```
% Exactly the same as `myrange = 2:5;` but allows for matrix ops like (2:5).' or (1:4) + 1
myrange = (2:5);
```

To concatenate vectors you can use square brackets, so...

```
% This is valid but not necessary
myrange = [2:5]; % >> [2 3 4 5]
% If you want to add non-continuous values, you could concatenate using
myrange = [2:4, 5]; % >> [2 3 4 5]
```

---

If your variable names are anything to go by, then you are indexing a [table](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) variable. If so, you can also index using a *cell array* of column names. i.e.

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;
mytable = table(a, b, c);

myrange = {'b', 'c'};
mytable(:, myrange); % >> columns b and c containing 2 and 3
```

Comment: so with table: curly for column names, round from indexes. 

My mistake was that I was using curly brackets for indexes.

Comment: Yes, you can't store character arrays (like `'myColumn1'`) in a matrix, so must be a cell array `{...}`. Indexes should always be in a numerical matrix though, so create one however suits you, parentheses `(...)` and the colon operator will do!

Comment: Another thing your answer makes clear is that the "range definition" is nothing other than an actual range of values. So if I have 2:5 as the value of a parameter, in fact I'm putting in an array with the values [2,3,4,5].  I thought it was some special construct or class that allowed the colon in the middle.Thank you!

Comment: @pashute No worries, form the documentation: *The colon is one of the most useful operators in MATLAB®. It can create vectors, subscript arrays, and specify for iterations.* Read more here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html